# sccs returns 'Permission denied'

Tags: permissions

I installed and set up the package "cssc", but when I try to use sccs with the command "sccs create filename" I receive the message "Permission denied".  The exit status of the command is 69, which I understand means "Could not exec program".

How can I get sccs to work properly?

Thanks very much,

tcnm

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://www.gnu.org/software/cssc/

Comment: Did you think about installing the real `SCCS` intead of the incomplete clone? Check http://sccs.sf.net BTW: I recommend to install `schilytools` as this gives you a more recent version.